# How can I get an assembly language listing of my Arduino Sketches on Windows?

Tags: windows, assembly, arduino

I would like to be able to see an assembly language listing of my Arduino sketches. How can I achieve this?

**Update:** I am running the Arduino Software on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `avr-objdump` on the `.elf` file created by the build. For example, on OS X I can do this:

```
$ cd ~/arduino-0015/examples/Digital/Blink/applet
$ avr-objdump -d Blink.elf
```

(Your path on Windows may be different, obviously.) This produces a disassembly of the code, part of which will look something like this:

```
0000013a <main>:
 13a:   0e 94 3e 01     call    0x27c <init>
 13e:   0e 94 97 00     call    0x12e <setup>
 142:   0e 94 80 00     call    0x100 <loop>
 146:   fd cf           rjmp    .-6             ; 0x142 <main+0x8>
```

Comment: More thorough instructions are here (for the less advanced person, your above info would not have been quite enough I think): http://rcarduino.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-view-arduino-assembly.html

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Linux, you can follow [this tutorial on how to compile for the Arduino without the IDE](http://www.johanneshoff.com/arduino-command-line.html).

Once you do that, you can get an assembly listing by running gcc with the -s flag.

Comment: @Magnus I'm running on Windows, but the link may still be of use - I'll take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The following (hacky) steps will provide assembly language listings of Arduino sketches and associated libraries on Windows:

1. Download (and rename) the [Arduino Windows command line batch files](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/WindowsCommandLine) into the directory containing your sketch (the `.pde` file)
2. Set up the required environment variables as specified in the above linked page
3. Add `-S` to the `abuild_gcc_opts` variable in `abuild.bat` (line 158)
4. Run `abuild -r -c <pde_filename>`
5. Expect to get the following warnings and errors, which you can ignore:

   `... warning: #warning "This file has been moved to <util/delay.h>."`

   `.\obj\<pde_filename>.cpp.o: file format not recognized: treating as linker script`

   `.\obj\<pde_filename>.cpp.o:1: syntax error`

The assembly language listings can be found in the `.o` files in the created `obj` directory. For example the listing for the sketch itself is in `obj\<pde_filename>.cpp.o`

Answer (score 0):

The -S (not s) flag show the c code as well.Also know as mixed listing:

linux: (.arduino/preferences.txt: delete_target_folder=false)

```
$ cd /tmp/buildxxxx.tmp
$ avr-objdump -dS Blink.cpp.elf

int main(void)
{
    init();
 2f4:   8a df           rcall   .-236       ; 0x20a <init>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Arduino compilation is set up with link-time optimization (LTO), and the assembly files created during C compilation don't contain any assembly code - just the intermediate representation used later in the LTO stage to generate actual assembly code. We want the latter.

It so happens, rather nicely, that the very last time assembler is invoked in the entire compilation process, is to take the output from the LTO stage, and turn it into a whole-application object file.

To get at this assembly file, do the following:

1. Open `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.3\platform.local.txt` (create it if it doesn't exist). Add the following line

   ```
   compiler.c.elf.extra_flags=-save-temps=obj -fverbose-asm
   ```

   If there already is such a line there, just add the above options (to the right of `=`).

   **Note:** If you can't find the folder, look for the following files: `boards.txt`, `platform.txt`, `programmers.txt`. If you find these files in multiple locations, the one you want should be *inside your home directory* (i.e. not in `Program Files` or `/Applications` or `/usr`), and should be correlated at least partially to the version of Arduino you're using (should you have multiple versions installed).
2. Build the sketch again.
3. Look for a file named `%TEMP%\cc*.ltrans.s`. Each build will create a new such file. If you sort them by timestamp, the newest one is for the most recent build.

**Note:** The environment variables, enclosed by `%` signs, are valid in the Windows dialog boxes. You can directly paste such a path into e.g. an Open or Save As... dialog box, and it'll work. Paths with globs (`*`) will act as filters (IIRC).

To know which exact `cc*.s` file was generated, add the verbose option to the final binary generator pass:

```
compiler.c.elf.extra_flags=-save-temps=obj -fverbose-asm -v
```

Rebuild, and copy-paste all the output from the compilation status window in Arduino to e.g. Notepad++, and search for `ar.exe`. The sole line that contains `ar.exe` ends with the name of this `cc` file:

```
 c:/users/[...omitted...]/avr/bin/as.exe -mmcu=avr6 -mno-skip-bug 
    -o C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3XhU2F.ltrans0.ltrans.o
    C:\Users\[...]\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3XhU2F.ltrans0.ltrans.s
```

How does the file look? This is a short extract, just to show that both the C source and the assembly are intermingled - and this represents exactly the binary embedded in the `.hex` file and sent to the target.

```
.LBE33:
.LBE32:
.LBB34:
.LBB35:
 ;  C:\Users\[...]\Documents\Arduino\sketch_jul01a\sketch_jul01a.ino:29:   pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    .file 4 "C:\\Users\\[...]\\Documents\\Arduino\\sketch_jul01a\\sketch_jul01a.ino"
    .loc 4 29 0
    ldi r22,lo8(1)   ; ,
    ldi r24,lo8(13)  ; ,
    call pinMode     ; 
.LVL55:
 ;  C:\Users\[...]\Documents\Arduino\sketch_jul01a\sketch_jul01a.ino:30:   pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
    .loc 4 30 0
    ldi r22,lo8(1)   ; ,
    ldi r24,lo8(12)  ; ,
    call pinMode     ; 
.LVL56:
 ;  C:\Users\[...]\Documents\Arduino\sketch_jul01a\sketch_jul01a.ino:31:   pinMode(ldrPin, INPUT);
    .loc 4 31 0
    ldi r22,0    ; 
    ldi r24,lo8(54)  ; ,
    call pinMode     ; 
.LVL57:
.LBE35:
.LBE34:
.LBB36:
.LBB37:
```

This approach also works on Linux and MacOS, except that the paths are slightly different, and path expansion uses different syntax. The two files of concern still are `platform.local.txt` - a file you must create, since it doesn't exist at first, and the `${TEMP}/cc*.ltrans.s` files.