# How do you get the assembly code for a program in the Arduino IDE (macOS)?

Tags: assembly, gcc, command-line, arduino, objdump

I am trying to get the assembly code of my Arduino program (One of the comments in this question explains [why I need the assembly code](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/636851/what-happens-if-you-try-to-run-code-faster-than-your-arduino-can-handle?noredirect=1#comment1686897_636851)). I've seen many answers to this question that say to use ["objdump"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919781/how-can-i-get-an-assembly-language-listing-of-my-arduino-sketches-on-windows) or["gcc"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476682/how-do-you-compile-high-level-code-to-get-assembly-code) command on the terminal, but whenever I try to run these commands on my computer it tells me "{command} is not recognized as an internal or external command".

I then proceed to try and download these commands by [following guides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054534/how-to-use-install-gnu-binutils-objdump), but I have found these guides are extremely hard to follow and they skip steps. Plus they seem kind of outdated.

Can someone show me an idiot proof way to get the assembly code without skipping steps? **I have access to both a mac and a windows computer, but no linux.**

Comment: Based on that error message, you are running Windows.  You need to find out where the gcc commands are located on your computer, and add that directory to your path.  It's probably wherever the Arduino tools were installed.  Your Mac should be able to run `objdump` immeditely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I finally managed to do this on mac:

**First:** Find the file path of your Arduino program. Do this by going to your Arduino program in the IDE, select the "Arduino" tab at the top, then select "Preferences". This should pull up a Preferences box where you can check the "Compilation" box under the "Show verbose output during:" section, then select "OK".

Here is a picture of what i'm talking about:

[image]

Now when you go into your program in the Arduino IDE and you click the "verify" button you should be able to find your .elf file in the terminal window. Copy the line located directly above "Sketch uses xxx bytes (x%) of program storage space..." (I have highlighted the line you are looking for below):

[image]

Here is the line I have Highlighted: `/private/var/folders/d7/ffdh68g156vdshm9gq4pf3440000gn/T/AppTranslocation/FFDDB455-276F-4474-8B17-B9A99F34B321/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-size -A /var/folders/d7/ffdh68g156vdshm9gq4pf3440000gn/T/arduino_build_829591/Working_Sep25_PMOS_Sketch.ino.elf`

You can now erase everything before the -A flag and only copy this part: `/var/folders/d7/ffdh68g156vdshm9gq4pf3440000gn/T/arduino_build_829591/Working_Sep25_PMOS_Sketch.ino.elf`

**Second:** follow this guide which shows you [how to download the `avr-gcc` package](https://github.com/osx-cross/homebrew-avr) which you are going to need.

**Third:** Open the terminal and run this command: `avr-objdump -S {insert path to your .elf file we copied earlier}. You should now have access to the assembly code.